# To use Place type other than supported place type in Google map place api

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on Google map places API and I am new to this. I created a sample project where I am able to retrieve latitudes and longitudes of nearby restaurants. But now I want to retrieve tattoo shops near by. But "tattoo shops" are not the supported type in google places API. Can some one tell me how to do that. I couldnot find any way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `keyword=tattoo+shops` rather than `type=restaurant` in your request.

(I'm assuming you're using [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) in the Google Places API Web Service.)